# Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Every time I click the button to add items to the table the app crashes and I get this error, logcat:

```
    11-30 21:46:00.822 13943-13943/com.example.user.timetable_test E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "TABLESunday": syntax error
11-30 21:46:00.827 13943-13943/com.example.user.timetable_test D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
11-30 21:46:00.827 13943-13943/com.example.user.timetable_test E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                 Process: com.example.user.timetable_test, PID: 13943
                                                                                 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "TABLESunday": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLESunday(_session INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,_name TEXT,_length INTEGER);
                                                                                 #################################################################
                                                                                 Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
                                                                                 Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
                                                                                    (near "TABLESunday": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLESunday(_session INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,_name TEXT,_length INTEGER);)
                                                                                 #################################################################
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1058)
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:623)
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:59)
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1812)
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1743)
                                                                                     at com.example.user.timetable_test.setup.TableDBHandler.onCreate(TableDBHandler.java:43)
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:251)
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
                                                                                     at com.example.user.timetable_test.setup.TableDBHandler.addEntry(TableDBHandler.java:63)
                                                                                     at com.example.user.timetable_test.setup.SetTable$PlaceholderFragment$1.onClick(SetTable.java:206)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5697)
                                                                                     at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10826)
                                                                                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22526)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7225)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

SQLitDatabase class:

```
package com.example.user.timetable_test.setup;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import com.example.user.timetable_test.MiscData;


public class TableDBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    private MiscData data = MiscData.getInstance();

    private static int      DATABASE_VERSION   = 1;
    private static String   DATABASE_NAME      = "Timetable.db";
    private static  String[] TABLE_DAY          = new String[MiscData.getInstance().getDays()];
    private static  String   COLUMN_SESSION_NUM = "_session";
    private static  String   COLUMN_NAME        = "_name";
    private static  String   COLUMN_LENGTH      = "_length";


    public TableDBHandler(Context context, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory){

        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase){

        for(int i = 0; i < data.getDays(); i++){

            TABLE_DAY[i] = data.getDay(i + data.getFirstDay());

        }

        for(int i = 0; i < data.getDays(); i++){
            String query = "CREATE TABLE" + TABLE_DAY[i] + "(" + COLUMN_SESSION_NUM +
                           " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT " + COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT " +
                           COLUMN_LENGTH + " INTEGER " + ");";

            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(query);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1){

        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE EXISTS" + TABLE_DAY);
        onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);

    }


    public void addEntry(int day, String name, int length){

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_NAME, name);
        values.put(COLUMN_LENGTH, length);

        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.insert(TABLE_DAY[day], null, values);
        db.close();

    }


    //get Session length
    public int getSessionLength(int day, int session){

        int            length;
        SQLiteDatabase db    = getReadableDatabase();
        String         query =
                "SELECT" + COLUMN_LENGTH + "FROM" + TABLE_DAY[day] + "WHERE" + COLUMN_SESSION_NUM +
                "=\"" + session + "\";";

        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);

        length = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_LENGTH));

        return length;

    }


    //get Session name
    public String getSessionName(int day, int session){

        String         name;
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT" + COLUMN_NAME + "FROM" + TABLE_DAY[day] +
                       "WHERE" + COLUMN_SESSION_NUM + "=\"" + session + "=\";";

        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);

        name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME));

        return name;
    }

}
```

In this code I try to make an array of tables initialized at run-time, this might be where the error comes from or I might be just derping.

Where I add an entry:

```
tableDBHandler.addEntry(page , sessionSpinners[i].toString(), Integer.parseInt(lengthText[i].getText().toString()));
```

I have tried changing the data type of `COLUMN_LENGTH` from `TEXT` to `INTEGER`, but this didn't work.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is into the create of table `"TABLESunday": syntax error`. There is missing a space on the syntax on your sql code. Try this:

```
String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_DAY[i] + "(" + COLUMN_SESSION_NUM +
                       " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT " + COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT " +
                       COLUMN_LENGTH + " INTEGER " + ");";
```

Comment: @Omar You also need to carefully consider using `AUTOINCREMENT`, there is very likely no need. `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` will provided a unique key normally 1,2,3...... You may also consider using `_id` instead of `_session`. It may make things easier if you use a cursor adapter, which requires `_id`. `AUTOINCREMENT` will make that key unique within the whole database and as such has overheads. You may wish to read [SQLite Autoincrement](http://sqlite.org/autoinc.html)

Comment: thank you for the answer and the advice. BTW it worked

Answer (score 0):

in my case number of "columns names" and "values" not match.
for example

```
insert INTO cars (car_id,Name) values (v1,v2,v3);
```

columns number is 2 and values is 3;

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I use SQLite to update name of table.
That's all!

Answer (score 0):

I am dumb or its my bad, None of the above given solution worked for me, I was creating database on `External Storage` and the app doesn't had the `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permissions, resolved by granting permission, thanks